# C++ program to keep reading integers from the user until the sum of two consecutive input numbers is larger than or equal to 10

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to solve but not getting the desired output.
C++ program to keep reading integers from the user until the sum of two consecutive input numbers is larger than or equal to 10.
then the program will output the sum of all positive input numbers.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    int num_1, num_2, result=0;

    int i;

    int results=0;

    cout << "Enter the value : ";
    cin >> num_1;

    cout << "Enter the value : ";
    cin >> num_2;

    if (num_1 > 0 && num_2 > 0)
    {
        results = num_1 + num_2;
    }


    do
    {   
        if (results <= 10)
        {
            for(i=0;i<=result;i++)
            {
                cout << "Enter the value : ";

                cin >> num_1;

                cout << "Enter the value : ";

                cin >> num_2;
                
                result = num_1 + num_2+results ;

                cout << "Result = " << result;

                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    while (result <= 10);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `for(i=0;i<=result;i++)` loop? It say that the sum of the numbers is the amount of number you want to read. (The condition you want is "while the sum of `num_1` and `num_2` is less than ten", "while `i` is less than the sum of all the numbers".)

Comment: Also, if you read two numbers, then two numbers, then two numbers, you will never check the sum of the second and third numbers, or the fourth and the fifth, and so on. Work out a procedure without writing any code first.

Comment: I think you might have confused `result` and `results` in some places, I'd recommend using more descriptive variable names

Comment: Possible implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/3ahM5z9T5

Comment: Tip: forget about the sum of all the numbers for now (BTW: you only want the sum of the *positive* numbers). Focus on just reading numbers until the sum of two consecutive numbers is at least ten. Once that works, the summation is not difficult to add.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem with a few easy steps, with no need for multiple loops.

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    int sum_of_all_positive_nums { };
    bool isLessThan { };

    std::cout << "Enter the value: ";
    int num_1;
    std::cin >> num_1;

    if ( num_1 > 0 ) { sum_of_all_positive_nums += num_1; }

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the value: ";
        int num_2;
        std::cin >> num_2;

        const int sumOfTwoNums { num_1 + num_2 };
        isLessThan = ( sumOfTwoNums < 10 ) ? true : false;

        if ( num_2 > 0 ) { sum_of_all_positive_nums += num_2; }

        if ( isLessThan ) { std::cout << "\nRepeat!\n"; num_1 = num_2; }

    } while ( isLessThan );

    std::cout << "\nSum of all positive numbers == "
              << sum_of_all_positive_nums << '\n';

    std::cin.get( );
}
```

**Sample input/output:**

```
Enter the value: -2
Enter the value: 3

Repeat!
Enter the value: 4

Repeat!
Enter the value: 5

Repeat!
Enter the value: 5

Sum of all positive numbers == 17
```

**A few important notes:**

1. Do not use `using namespace std;` at the global scope.
2. Do not declare multiple variables in a single statement.
3. Do not use platform-specific features like `system("pause");`.

Comment: I tested this with the input `1 2 9`, and it said that the sum is 14, but it's 12. With `1 2 9 9`, it said 21, but it should still be 12.

Comment: @molbdnilo But the number of entered values must be even, how did it accept 3 values?

Comment: Why do you think there must be an even number of inputs? The problem description doesn't say that. `1 2 9` has two pairs of two consecutive numbers each: `1 2` and `2 9`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, I think I fixed it. See if it's ok.